# Virtuemart - Booked, ordered products Inventory value not updating

Tags: virtuemart, inventory, stock

I am developing a shop to sell tea online, its 99% completed and developed using the following version of Joomla and Virtue Mart.

Joomla! 2.5.20  --- Virtue Mart 2.6.10

My problem is, when an order is placed and its status is changed to 'Shipped' from 'Pending' the 'Booked, ordered products' value under 'Inventory' for the ordered product does not get updated.

It just does not get updated based on the orders placed or products placed in a users shopping cart.

I tried all possible options to the best to my knowledge but was not able to find a solutions to it.

Request all to help me resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set how each order status affect **Stock Handling** under:

```
Components -> Virtuemart -> Order Statuses -> Stock handling
```

The default values are:

- **Shipped** -> Is removed -> update **In Stock** value
- **Pending** -> Is reserved -> updates both **In Stock** and **Booked, ordered products** value

Hope this helps